# My has_many through database is not accepting data?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to save data in 2 different tables using the **has_many through** relation and only one view but it's not working:

**My controller:**

```
def new
    @group = Group.new
    @group.memberships.build
end

def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    if @group.save
      flash[:success] = "Group created!"
      redirect_to @group
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'groups/new'
    end
end

def group_params
    params[:group][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params[:owner] = current_user.id
    params.require(:group).permit(:user_id, :name, :category, :description, memberships_attributes: [:user_id, :group_id, :owner])
end
```

**My Model:**

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :users, through: :memberships
has_many :posts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
```

**My form:**

```
<%= form_for(@group) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <% f.hidden_field :user_id %>
    <%= f.text_area :name, placeholder: "Group's name", class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.text_area :category, placeholder: "Category (i.e. #programming, #food, etc)", class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Description of the group", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <% f.fields_for :memberships do |mem| %>
    <% mem.hidden_field :user_id %>
    <% mem.hidden_field :group_id %>
    <% mem.hidden_field :owner %>
<% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**And my schema is:**

```
create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "user_id"
t.string  "name"
t.string  "category"
t.text    "description"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_groups_on_user_id"
end

create_table "memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "group_id"
t.integer  "owner"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_group_id"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_user_id"
end
```

Can someone help me save user info inside the group and membership data and the group data inside the membership table please.

Here is my log:

```
Started POST "/groups" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-25 00:21:06 -0500
Processing by GroupsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kOmM3x84+dbS+n4HkdnqMoX4NBlZYohUldCQdSAHJbge0+iAzGhX5KRPQG3sQ5bCV2NDqCCr3bFqvz/lBRChHg==", "group"=>{"name"=>"qqqqq", "category"=>"q", "description"=>"q"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Group Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "groups" WHERE LOWER("groups"."name") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "qqqqq"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "groups" ("user_id", "name", "category", "description") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 2], ["name", "qqqqq"], ["category", "q"], ["description", "q"]]
   (12.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/groups/19
Completed 302 Found in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 14.8ms)
```

Comment: What are the `params` that are generated in the server log?

Comment: @Pavan Hello! That's the thing, at first it appeared like it was commiting the transaction but then it used to make a rollback and didn't tell me why. and know it shows no errors.

Comment: Just post the params that are being displyed

Comment: I put them up inside the question.

Comment: Can you set the params like you've done in your controller? I think the params[:group] and params[:owner] are empty.

Comment: @dhaliman like this: def create
    params[:group][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params[:owner] = current_user.id

Comment: @dhaliman already done it but still not working

Comment: Set user id and owner to current user id in Group.new

Comment: You can also set the values to your hidden fields using the value attribute and you'll get the correct values in the params for user and owner. Though I feel this might not be safe.

Comment: @dhaliman yor are saying to set them inside Group.new?

Comment: Yeah. Set them in Group.new instead of params.

Comment: @dhaliman ok so now is telling me this: Memberships user must exist
Memberships group must exist. Think I'm getting closer to the solution; think I have a problem getting the user_id and group_id. Any ideas??

Comment: The memberships user and group doesn't exist. You've to create them first.

Comment: @dhaliman Ok, can you please explain me how to do that? I'm actually new at RoR

Comment: You've to create the user using User.new or whatever the name of your model name is.

Comment: Ok, and then pass it to the view?